# Как назначить областям со стрелками переключение слайдов?

Tags: html, css

Как назначить областям со стрелками переключение слайдов? (В данный момент это осуществляется синими прямоугольниками) Использовать можно **только HTML+CSS**

Пытался сделать, но не выходит.

https://codepen.io/georgeye/pen/VwPVNEW

синяя кнопка задается таким кодом в css(непонятно вот как это можно связать с элементом 'a'):

```
 /*настройка переключения и положения для левой стрелки*/
#switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2){
    background-color: blue; 
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Весь код:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <section class="content">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Список</h1>
          <div class="content__inner">
            <div class="content__list">
              <ul>
                <li>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia</li>
                <li>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia</li>
                <li>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia</li>
                <li>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia</li>
                <li>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
    
            <div class="content__slider">
              <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
                <article id="slider">
                    <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
                    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
                    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
                  <div id="slides">
                    <div id="overflow">
                      <div class="image">
                        <article><img src="html-css.png">
                          <div class="box">
                            <div>
                              <h3>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit</h3>
                              <p>Quia dolor ipsum quia dolor sit</p> 
                            </div>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                              <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </article>
                        <article><img src="html-css.png">
                          <div class="box">
                            <div>
                              <h3>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit</h3>
                              <p>Quia dolor ipsum quia dolor sit</p> 
                            </div>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                              <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </article>
                        <article><img src="html-css.png">
                          <div class="box">
                            <div>
                              <h3>Quisquam dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit</h3>
                              <p>Quia dolor ipsum quia dolor sit</p> 
                            </div>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                              <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </article>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="controls">
                    <label for="switch1"></label>
                    <label for="switch2"></label>
                    <label for="switch3"></label>
                  </div>
                </article>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </body>
    </html>

**CSS:**

    html{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    *, *::before, *::after{
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    
    body{
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    ul{
      display: block;
    }
    li{
      list-style: none;
    }
    .container{
      max-width: 1170px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 15px;
      background-color:gainsboro;
    }
    
    /*content*/
    .content__slider{
      padding: 0px 15px;
    }
    .content__list{
      font-size: 25px;
      width: 42%;
    }
    .content__inner{
      display: flex;
    }
    .content__slider{
      width: 58%;
    }
    
    /* Слайдер */
    .content__slider{
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #slides article{
      width: 30.2%;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .content__slider input[type=radio]{
      display: none;
    }
    #slides .image{ /*устанавливает общий размер блока с изображениями*/
        width: 330%;
        line-height: 0;
    }
    
    #overflow{ /*сркывает все, что находится за пределами этого блока*/
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    article img{ /*размер изображений слайдера*/
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /*настройка переключения и положения для левой стрелки*/
    #switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
    #switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
    #switch3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2){
        background-color: blue; 
        float: left;
        display: block;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
    }
    
    /*настройка переключения и положения для правой стрелки*/
    #switch1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
    #switch2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
    #switch3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1){
        background-color: blue; 
        float: right;
        display: block;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
    }
    
    label, a{ /*при наведении на стрелки или переключатели - курсор изменится*/
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /*позиция изображения при активации переключателя*/
    #switch1:checked ~ #slides .image{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    #switch2:checked ~ #slides .image{
        margin-left: -100%;
    }
    
    #switch3:checked ~ #slides .image{
        margin-left: -200%;
    }
    
    #controls{ /*положение блока всех управляющих элементов*/
        margin: -25% 0 0 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    #slides .image{ /*анимация пролистывания изображений*/
        transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
    
    }
    
    #controls label:hover{ /*прозрачность стрелок при наведении*/
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    
    #controls label{ /*прозрачность стрелок при отводе курсора*/
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    
    /*Элементы слайдера*/
    
    .box{
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .box div{
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
    
    .box li{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .box a{
      border-left: 1px solid #302c2b;
      display: block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 24px;
    
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .fa-angle-left i::before{
      content: "\f104";
      font: FontAwesome;
      font-size: 26px;
    }
    .fa-angle-rigth i::before{
      content: "\f104";
      font: FontAwesome;
      font-size: 26px;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//// What make initial buttons
$(".btn1").on("click", function() {
  alert("left original")
});
$(".btn2").on("click", function() {
  alert("right original")
});

/// New button work
$(".btnNew1").on("click", function() {
  $(".btn1").trigger('click');
});

$(".btnNew2").on("click", function() {
  $(".btn2").trigger('click');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
}

.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn1"></button>
  <button class="btn btn2"></button>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <button class="newBtn btnNew1">New left</button>
  <button class="newBtn btnNew2">New right</button>
</div>
```

Если совсем примитивно, то это делается как-то так. Но опять же я не рекомендую создавать новые DOM элементы

Comment: это конечно хорошо, но я не смогу это интегрировать под свою задачу(использовать только html+css)
получается, без js никак не обойтись , как я понял, невозможно сделать привязку переключателей к элементу button или 'a'

Comment: без js ни как. Как с js я показал .

Answer (score 0):

Если используете jquery то можно через  `clone()` подвязав клик по новым кнопкам  c кнопками слайдера. Не рекомендую это делать, насколько я вижу вашу задачу это можно решить через CSS / Опустив готовые кнопки через `position:absolute; top:calc(100% + 50px); right:0;` и задав нужные стили

Comment: Этого будет недостаточно, при изменении окна синие "квадратики" будут вести себя не так как нужно, хотелось бы сделать привязку именно к элементу "a" в котором и находится стрелка

Comment: Дело конечно ваше, но это плохая практика создания доп элементов если они уже есть / В любом случае вам лучше ставить "button" а не "a"

Comment: @ BlackStar1991 можно и button. Я привязку не знаю как сделать к кнопкам, вот в чем был вопрос, опыта мало

Comment: можно ли это реализовать?